# open a new url on button click windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to open a link on a button click in windows 10 Universal app. I used web view but it does not seem to work. how to open a url (eg. facebook.com or google.com) on a button click. I am using XAML and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this in Button Click event handler?

`await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("uri address"));`

Comment: Right after I posted the question i did try Launcher.Launchuriasync() and it worked. I was going to update the post. Thank you so much.